# How to fix an aborted ftp connection

Tags: ftp, connection

I'm trying to upload quite a big file (1.7 GB) to my ftp server. There is only one problem: every single time i get to 44% the connection shuts down, reconnects itself and then start again at 0%.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? It would make me really happy.

Here's is the error:

```
Status: Resolving address of '''''''''''''''
Status: Connecting to '''.'''.''.''':''...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Starting upload of ''''''''''''''''''
Status: Connection closed by server
Command:    CWD '''''''''
Response:   250 CWD command successful
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "'''''''''" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (''',''','',''',''',''').
Command:    STOR ''''''''''''
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for ''''''''''''
Error:  Transfer connection interrupted: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  File transfer failed after transferring 1.020.526.592 bytes in 1313 seconds
Status: Disconnected from server
```

The ''' are sensitive information, it doesn't really look like that.

Note: I myself have no experience with ftp servers or whatever, I use a ftp-server from my webhost. No idea if that matters, but I better have said it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Contact your webhost and get their help to fix the issue, which appears to be on their side.
- Split the file into smaller pieces and reassemble. There are Linux commands such as [split](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-can-i-split-a-file-to-several-smaller-pieces/) and multiplatform tools such as [HJ-Split](http://www.hjsplit.org/windows/).
- Use another transfer method such as SSH using [puTTY](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/linux/) or [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

Comment: Thanks! The splitting worked. Also i found another solution myself. I use FileZilla for my ftp-connection. When i was halfway the upload, I manually aborted it. If you start the upload again it will say the file already exists. It gives you a few options. One of them is to resume the upload.